# How to set binary data using setBlob() in C++ connector

Tags: c++, mysql, binary, blob, sqlconnection

I know this has been asked before, and I tried to implement the solution, but I just get exception errors when I call ps->executeUpdate(). Has anyone got an explicit example?

Comment: "and I tried to implement the solution" How are we supposed to know what you've tried if you don't post any code?  It would also help to know what tutorials/examples you're using.

Answer (score 1):

This post is a bit old, but I ran across the same question. I employed the method above and it didn't quite work right for my case, which was trying to take a vector and use that for the stream. What I was doing was taking a UUID and converting it into a 16 byte binary version to use in the table. Using the method above, I found that only half my buffer was being populated.

I ended up using a `stringstream`.

```
std::vector<unsigned char>  convertedId;
std::stringstream           stream;

// convertedId has been populated with the 16 byte binary version
stream = std::stringstream(std::string(convertedId.begin(), convertedId.end()));
// Parameter 1 is BINARY(16)
pStatement->setBlob(1, &stream);
```

A few other things to keep in mind. The stream is not accessed until one of the `execute` variants is called. So you'll need to keep the stream around until you have run `execute`.

Hopefully this will help someone and save them time.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Matthew - I assumed the previous answer to this question (by elrohin). Maybe I should have replied to that. Anyway heres the code he suggested:

```
class DataBuf : public streambuf
{
public:
   DataBuf(char * d, size_t s) {
      setg(d, d, d + s);
   }
};


// prepare sql update statement etc. and set the data pointer
string* pData = ; // ...not part of the original answer

DataBuf buffer((char*)pData->data(), pData->length());
istream stream(&buffer);
ps->setBlob(1, &stream);
ps->executeUpdate(); // This causes an exception in free.c
```

I'm using VS9 with the latest (beta) connector/cpp debug libs. I've also tried using char* instead of string.

Comment: If an exception is raised in free.c, that means bad things happened with memory. I'm looking straight at that char cast.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me:

```
  Driver *driver;
  Connection *conn;

  driver = get_driver_instance();
  conn = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");

  std::auto_ptr use_stmt(conn->createStatement());
  use_stmt->execute("USE world");

  std::auto_ptr stmt(conn->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO terrain_texture_tiles_0 (data) VALUES(?)"));
  std::string value("A\0B", sizeof("A\0B") - 1);
    std::istringstream tmp_blob(value);
    stmt->setBlob(1, &tmp_blob);
    stmt->execute();
```

hope it helps ... Jaroslav Pribyl