# Add and Retrieve array of custom datatype in mongodb using the C++ driver

Tags: c++, arrays, mongodb, binary-data

I have an array of custom datatype such as a class or a structure and would like to store it in mongodb as binary data. 
How would I go about adding and retrieving that array from mongodb? 
I need to do this via the C++ driver.
I was able to add and retrieve for simple arrays using appendbinData and getbinData but I can't find a way to do this for arrays of custom datatypes.

Comment: try serialization, such as msgpack, protobuf or json or xml

Comment: All of these require you to define a way to serialize the datatype. Though what I am using is a complex datatype from a library. Is it possible to just dump this data and extract without having to go through the code of the complex datatype and finding out ways to serialize each component?

Comment: For example the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1110271/3203830).

Comment: you can dump anything you want, but in c++ you need to know the details of your type. You can help yourself with libraries to write as little boilerplate as possible